# create new array from two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, conditional-statements, flatten

I have two arrays with the same keys, but different values.

Example:

```
(
    "2"=> 6,
    "5"=> 1
),
(
    "2"=> 1,
    "5"=> 3
)
```

I want to create a new array with the same keys, but replace the highest values like this:

```
 (
    "2"=> 6,
    "5"=> 3
)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate getting the maximum value for each key, which you can do with a combination of [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```php
$keys = array_keys(reset($arr) ?: []);
$res = array_combine(
    $keys,
    array_map(fn ($k) => max(array_column($arr, $k)), $keys)
    );
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 6
    [5] => 3
)
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/v3efA)

For those using PHP prior to 7.4, you can replace the arrow function with

```php
function ($k) use ($arr) { return max(array_column($arr, $k)); }
```

Note that this code assumes that all the sub-arrays have the same keys or some subset of the keys of the first sub-array.

Comment: Would you implement such a snippet with so many function calls in a professional project?  Why the longhanded anonymous function?  As an aside, this snippet relies on the fact the the first array contains all keys that exist in any subsequent row.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested loop, check if the key is encountered for the first time or if the stored value for that key is less than the current value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6NqYK))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($result[$k]) || $result[$k] < $v) {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

A functional-style script with nested `array_reduce()` calls isn't nearly as readable. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/K1SYq))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        fn($result, $row) => array_reduce(
            array_keys($row),
            fn($res, $k) => isset($res[$k]) && $res[$k] >= $row[$k]
                ? $res
                : array_replace($res, [$k => $row[$k]]),
            $result
        ),
        []
    )
);
```